# How do I access rails form_for options in a form builder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, formbuilder

If I've got a form declaration like the following:

```
<%= form_for(@thing, {foo: 'bar', builder: AwesomeBuilder}) do |f| 
  ...
<% end %>
```

Is there any way I can access the form's option hash in the declaration for AwesomeBuilder? I'm trying to  Something like:

```
class AwesomeBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def text_field(method, options={})
    options.reverse_merge!(form_for_options[foo])
    @template.content_tag(:div, super)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
class AwesomeBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def text_field(method, options={})
    options.reverse_merge!(self.options[:foo])
    @template.content_tag(:div, super)
  end
end
```